# Adding multiple columns to DataTable quickly using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datacolumn

Here is what I'm currently using.  It works fine, but takes several seconds to complete.  Is there a faster way?  I've tried creating a list of DataColumn and using table.columns.addRange(list.toArray) with no improvement.  I just need the columns to be numbered from 0 to 67.

```
If appTable.Columns.Count = 0 Then
    'adds columns 0 to 67 to table                
    For x = 0 To 67 Step 1
        appTable.Columns.Add(x, GetType(String))
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Start with putting `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file - that code will not even compile.  It only takes 1.2 secs for me - not sure what your expectations are.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Adding columns to an in memory DataTable shouldn't be a huge bottleneck by itself. Does your Table have any rows? Is it bound to some UI that might be doing updating? Does is have a linked DataSet with Relations that need checking?

Comment: using x.ToString I get 6 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot.  user6144226 answered my question.  I was using the DataTable as the DataSource for a DataGridView prior to adding the columns.  This is what caused the bottleneck.

I added the columns to the DataTable prior to setting it as the DataSource and everything runs much more quickly.  Thank you for your responses.